# "Duplicate data" or "duplicated data"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm making a presentation and I need to know if I should use "duplicated data" or "duplicate data". Is there any difference? I'm talking about removing observations of a database that are duplicates.

Comment: You mean "observed instances of" perhaps?

Comment: I would go with duplicate data as is the case in duplicate records.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers. I learned a lot. English is not my first language and in Portuguese we don't have this distinction between duplicate and duplicated. All answers are great and I voted for all (I really like approval voting!). However, I can only choose one as accepted answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference is subtle, but in this case, Duplicate Data would be preferred. I would interpret the two phrases as follows:

Duplicate Data: Entries that have been added by a system user multiple times, for example, re-registering because you have forgotten your details.

Duplicated Data: Someone has deliberately taken a precise duplicate of the data - or a proportion of it - maybe for backup or reporting purposes. It may have been accidentally added to the original.

In the context of what you are talking about, the difference is important, because the second implies exact duplicates, whereas the first is a much more complex issue.

And yes, "exact duplicate" and "partial duplicate" are misnomers - it is either a duplicate or not - but these are the terms used.

Comment: Yup, I would interpret the difference between the two forms exactly as you describe. To put it concisely, *duplicate* is accidental, *duplicated* is deliberate.

Comment: @Marthaª - yes simplistically, but Duplicated can also be accidental. But as a rule, you are right.

Comment: I think this is a spurious distinction - just because we use both forms doesn't mean they have to have different meanings.

Comment: @Marthaª and *duplicate* can also be deliberate. I think it more matters what the source of the data is. See my answer :)

Comment: Accidental and deliberate are literary senses as construed by the reader and thus, subjective. This is not relevant in a strictly technical context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But in the context, they DO have different meanings, and the meanings are important.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat: I understand that a system may contain multiple copies of the same data because it was *entered* more than once, and/or because existing data was *replicated*. What I don't accept is that any sensible writer would expect his readers to recognise which you kind he was referring to on the basis of it being called *duplicate* or *duplicated*.

Answer (score 12):

Other answers are good, but in my words:

*Duplicated data* used the old data as the source of the data.

```
process(X) -> A
A-> B
A is duplicated as B
```

*Duplicate data* had the same input and therefore are matching records.

```
process(X)  -> A
process(X)  -> B
B is a duplicate of A
```

Answer (score 6):

***Duplicate*** data.

What you discover and remove are instances of *duplicate* data.

What you or the processes create, mostly for a purpose, is *duplicated* data.

Comment: I think purpose is the keyword here.

Answer (score 4):

When I hear (or read) *duplicate data*, I presume *duplicate* is an adjective that modifies the word *data*.

Most of the dictionaries I consulted listed *[duplicate](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/duplicate_8)* as a noun, verb, and adjective, but *[duplicated](http://www.wordnik.com/words/duplicated)* as a verb.  For that reason, I'd use *duplicate data*.